# ClickOnce fails on download

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce

OK, I have a similar problem as [Download ClickOnce fails from setup.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244507/download-clickonce-fails-from-setup-exe) and [Download ClickOnce fails from setup.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244507/download-clickonce-fails-from-setup-exe) , where I have deployed a ClickOnce installer for a desktop app I am selling.

Different than those examples, I am using Visual Studio 2012 (Pro Version). Using .Net 3.5. I am deploying on a hosted LINUX machine. It worked for me and other people running Windows 7 & 8, possibly earlier versions of Widnows. Then after running a few tests in Debug mode, I built and deployed in Release mode. Now, the auto-installer breaks when it gets to the spot where it wants to download the `.application` file. Here's the log file.

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.2.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0', phase BuildList
Attempting to find 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YADDAYADDA' in the Global Assembly Cache
AssemblyCheck: Error querying assembly info: -2147024894
Attempting to find 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YADDAYADDA, processorArchitecture=msil' in the Global Assembly Cache
Assembly found at 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll'
Setting value '11.0.50727.1 {version}' for property 'VBPowerPacksInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0':
Property: [VBPowerPacksInstalled] = 11.0.50727.1 {version}
Running checks for command 'VBPowerPacks\VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'VBPowerPacksInstalled': true
Result of checks for command 'VBPowerPacks\VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1', phase BuildList
Reading value 'SP' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNet35SP'
The following properties have been set for package '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1': Property: [DotNet35SP] = 1 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFx35setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet35SP' and value '1': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFx35setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697205'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://www.mywebsite.com/ProductName/Downloads/oneclick/ProductName.application'.
```

I've looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx , after which I set the MIME type of `.application` to `x-ms-application`. No difference.

When I put the url `http://www.mywebsite.com/ProductName/Downloads/oneclick/ProductName.application` into my browser, I get the text of the file, rather than a download.

Any thoughts??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the first thing that got me closer to the solution was simply to reboot the PC I was dwonloading onto. This got me further into the install, but I then ran into another problem, the solution to which I found at [ClickOnce application replace current installed fliles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921404/clickonce-application-replace-current-installed-fliles) . Clearing out the folder `C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`got me to where I could install and run the app fully.

Answer (score 0):

Window application in C #. My solution, I hope it serves someone. The domain server was damaged, I just changed the IP of the new DNS server. It was not necessary to join that new domain server IP.

[image: Image solution]

Answer (score 0):

The "An error occurred trying to download.." error occurs with one of our click-once apps and the solution is to turn off IE Enhanced Security from Server Manager (Server 2012R2+) on the target machine.